# Issue with including KineticJs library

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am trying to use KineticJS and doing my first steps. So I am downloaded the min.js from the site and inluded it on my site. my dir tree

```
.
├── css
├── html
│   └── orthocal.html
├── js
│   ├── kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js
│   ├── main.js
├──media
│   └── proline_ap_pa_ceph__17839_1340650087_1280_1280.png
```

the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="applicaton/javascript" src="../js/kinetic-v5.1.0.min2.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
        <title>OrthoCal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But while main.js is loaded nomrally kinetic library won't. In the chorme devs console it is included normally with the html file (in the elements tab) but not in the network tab (as a GET request). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/kinetic-v5.1.0.min2.js"></script>
```

You missed one "i" in application.

Also you should check if you want to include `kinetic-v5.1.0.min2.js` or `kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js` (without the "2").

Comment: yes true, I knew it was something my eyes literally couldn't see.

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us.

Comment: Again. After I initialize stage I get that there is no container in document with id container. This my Js code
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
 width:800,
 height:600,
 container:'container'
});

Comment: Never mind its because, I haven't loaded the DOM yet :)

Comment: That's because your JavaScript is loading before your HTML does. You should create a init() function with the declaration of the Kinetic.stage inside and call it in your body onload event. Like this:
<body onload="init()">

Comment: yes yes, I did it on window.load...Is it correct approach?

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way and it will be perfectly correct. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Your js filename is `kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js` but you are including `kinetic-v5.1.0.min2.js`

And `type="application/javascript"`